# Angularjs first attempt at dependency injection

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-service

I have a UserAddController and I want to be able to access a list of countries returned by a Web API.  The Web API returns data fine.  Here is my app.js where I get the data :

```
app.factory('Country', function ($resource) {
    return $resource(
        "/api/country/:Id",
        { Id: "@Id" },
        { "update": { method: "PUT" } });  
});
```

This is my Controller :

```
var UserAddController = function ($scope, $location, service, User) {

    $scope.action = "Add";
    $scope.countries = service.countries;

};
```

I am declaring and creating a service here :

```
app.factory('CountryService', CountryService);

function CountryService($resource) {
    return $resource(
       "/api/country/:Id",
       { Id: "@Id" },
       { "update": { method: "PUT" } });  
}
```

I am using the same code as above just for testing purposes.  I am injecting this service like this :

```
UserAddController.$inject = ['$scope', 'CountryService'];
```

This is my first attempt at dependency injection and I cannot figure out where I am going wrong.  The error I currently get is 'service is undefined'.  I have tried passing both the service and the Country object to the Controller with the same results.  Can anybody give any advice?

EDIT : In my Controller, this populates successfully with an alert in the code, but without the alert does not populate.  Any reason why this is?

```
function CountryService($rootScope, $http) {
    var self = {};

    //self.countries = [{ "$id": "1", "CountryId": 1, "CountryName": "United Kingdom" }, { "$id": "2", "CountryId": 2, "CountryName": "Republic of Ireland" }, { "$id": "3", "CountryId": 3, "CountryName": "Australia" }, { "$id": "4", "CountryId": 4, "CountryName": "New Zealand" }, { "$id": "5", "CountryId": 5, "CountryName": "United States" }, { "$id": "6", "CountryId": 6, "CountryName": "France" }, { "$id": "7", "CountryId": 7, "CountryName": "Germany" }, { "$id": "8", "CountryId": 8, "CountryName": "Finland" }];

    $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: '/api/country'
    }).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
        self.countries = data;
    });
    alert(self.countries);
    return self;
}
```

Comment: From where the `service` should be coming from? Where do you define it? Most importantly, you are only listing 2 dependencies in `UserAddController.$inject` while your controller expects 4 dependencies...

Comment: The only dependency it is currently using is $scope, so at this stage I should only need to add a dependency to CountryService, which is what I have done?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add other services/dependencies.

```
UserAddController.$inject = ['$scope', 
                             '$location', 
                             'CountryService', 
                             'UserService'];
```

I have assumed that last dependency is a service with name 'UserService'. It's signature would be

```
app.factory('UserService', UserService);
```

Edit :

You need to instantiate a new variable.

```
//Inside function body
$scope.countries = service.countries;
$scope.newCountry = $scope.countries.get({Id : someId},callbackFn);
```

Now you have a counrtry with 'someId' in $scope.newCountry

Comment: The only dependency it is currently using is $scope, so at this stage I should only need to add a dependency to CountryService?

Comment: Edit your controller function. `var UserAddController = function($scope, service){/*function body*/}`

Comment: Progress....no error message now, but no populating of the data either. Do I have my syntax wrong anywhere?

Comment: It looks like no call is made to api/Country in firebug

Comment: Just edited to tackle your new problem. I think you should first try credit card example from Angularjs documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you injected [ngResource](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource.%24resource).

```
app = angular.module("app", ['ngResource']);
```

You need to inject the modules correcly

```
UserAddController.$inject = ['$scope', '$location', 'CountryService', 'user'];
```

This is quoted the [doc](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/dev_guide.services.injecting_controllers).

> You can specify the service name by using the $inject property, which
>   is an array containing strings with names of services to be injected.
>   The name **must** match the corresponding service ID registered with
>   angular. **The order of the service IDs matters**: the order of the
>   services in the array will be used when calling the factory function
>   with injected parameters.

I created a [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/vVV8H/) and you can try.

Comment: Do I need to inject ngResource into the service as well?

Comment: @user517406 Please take a look at the doc http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource.$resource. You should be ok just load it with your app.

Comment: It looks like no call is made to api/Country in firebug